# Error with Import in python from the same folder

Tags: python, python-import

I have three files in folder

`exceptions.py`

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

`MyClass.py` which begins as:

```
from exceptions import MyException
```

And empty `__init__.py`

When I'm trying to import `MyClass.py` there is Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MyClass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from exceptions import MyException
ImportError: cannot import name MyException
```

I've read docs and a lot of articles but can't find what's wrong

Comment: is it empty init.py or __init__.py?

Comment: Do `import exceptions` and have a look what `dir(exceptions)` has to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard built-in module named `exceptions` which is imported instead of your `exceptions.py`.

You can either rename your `exceptions.py` or use dotted import:

`from .exceptions import MyException`

See https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the name exeptions.py as there already exists a module named exeptions, which has no class named Myexeption, so you are getting thus error. Just change the file name and you will be all right.